# HTTP.get pasándole un ID

Tags: angular, http-get

Estoy intentando ver el detalle de un objeto mediante una llamada a una URL tipo `localhost:8001\character\1234567890` siendo el numero final el ID de dicho objeto.

La llamada la hago en dos funciones en typescript. La primera de ellas hace la llamada por http.get:

```
getCharacterDetail(characterId: number) {
    return this.http.get(this.characterDetailApiUrl + characterId,{})
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
}
```

Esta función en principio me debería de resolver el objeto y darme todos sus detalles. Si lanzo la URL en navegador funciona correctamente.

La segunda función obtiene y setea el resultado en una variable para luego presentar el detalle en una ventana modal:

```
characterDetail(characterId: number) {
    this.asyncCharDetail = this.getCharacterDetail(characterId)
        .do(res => {
            console.log(res);
        })
        .map(res => res.results);
}
```

Pues bien, el `console.log()` no me imprime el objeto resultante...

Ese es el primer escollo. El segundo vendrá en sacar el popup modal cuando la llamada me devuelva datos.

Comment: Estas seguro q getCharacterDetail() setea la variable con ul json?

Comment: He hecho un `console.log(characterId)` y si, está llegando bien el id. Tambien he hecho un `console.log (this.characterDetailApiUrl + characterId)` y la URL está correcta

Comment: Si hago console.log de la llamada http.get() me devuelve esto por consola: `Observable {_isScalar: false, _subscribe: ƒ}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En angular el método get de http devuelve un observable, por lo que tendrías que suscribirte a ese observable.

```
characterDetail(characterId: number) {
    this.asyncCharDetail = this.getCharacterDetail(characterId)
        .subscribe(res => {
            console.log(res);
        })
        .map(res => res.results);
}
```

Espero que te sirva.
Saludos.